# How to return controlling terminal to original owner after forced TIOCSCTTY?

Tags: linux, tty

tty_ioctl(4)

TIOCSCTTY int arg

Make  the  given  terminal  the controlling terminal of the calling process.  The calling process must be a session leader and not have a controlling terminal already.  If this terminal is  already  the  controlling terminal of a different session group then the ioctl fails with EPERM, unless the caller is root (more precisely: has the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) and arg equals 1, in which case the terminal is stolen,  *and  all processes that had it as controlling terminal lose it.*

How to return controlling terminal to its original owner?

Comment: Obviously possible if load some specially crafted kernel module. But maybe the normal way exists. If there is function to "steam" the terminal then there should be one to "return" it back. /* Don't like in general how all that controlling terminals, session leaders, SIGTTINs and `no job control in this shell` works in linux. */

Comment: There will be lots of problem to consider. eg. the origin process already got a new controlling terminal; the origin process returns the terminal without knowing that it has been stolen

Comment: reptyr could help? https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty. It would ptrace into the process you stole it from, if you know what that process is. But again there are problems.